# React Native how to pass two events in the same animated event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two actions passed through setParams

```
componentWillMount() {
                  this.props.navigation.setParams({
                    animatedValue: this._animatedValue.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 800],
                    outputRange: [0, -70],
                    extrapolate: 'clamp'
                  }),
                  colorRange: this.x.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,49,56],
                    outputRange: ['rgba(0, 0, 0,0)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.1)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.2)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.3)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.4)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.5)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.6)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.7)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.8)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.9)' ,'rgba(255, 0, 0,1)'],
                    extrapolate: 'clamp'
                  })
                });
                }
```

and in my only use one animated event. How can I use both events when I scroll in vertically

```
<ScrollView onScroll={ Animated.event([{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this._animatedValue }}}] )} scrollEventThrottle={16} >
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `Animated.event` accepts as many arguments you want and you pass a nativeEvent or a custom listener to it, let's try this:

```
<ScrollView onScroll={ Animated.event(
  [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this._animatedValue }}}],
  { listener: this._customListener },
)} scrollEventThrottle={16}>
```

And have your listener like:

```
_customListener(e) {
  // do whatever you want using this.colorRange
}
```

Comment: Sure thing, also, could you please mark this answer as correct if it was what you were asking? @BeingExpert

Comment: i tried that but only one of the event is accepted and made my program very slow when i do it this way.